# How to work out time elapsed from this datetime stamp and return it in either minutes, hours or days as appropriate

Tags: php

I'm dealing with an api which is returning the date time stamp exactly as follows:

```
Mon, 14 May 2012 14:14:11 +0000
```

I would like process this so php works out how many minutes ago this was if the number of minutes is less than 60 else how many hours ago it was if the number of hours is less than 24 else the number of days.

Dates will never be older than a few weeks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `DateTime` class. It can parse that date.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$dt = new DateTime('Mon, 14 May 2012 14:14:11 +0000');
$interval = $now->diff($dt);

$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
```

Note that 'now' will be in your current time zone so you might want to pass the `DateTimeZone` parameters as well. More info is here: http://php.net/DateTime

The class should already be built into your PHP. You won't need to include it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it is what I was looking for. Can you explain what the '%i' part does? Then I can accept your answer ;)

Comment: Sure, the interval object has different format options. `%i` tells it to output minutes. More info here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php